# android async task error with UI thread

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-adapter

Firstly, I read all answers related with this problem but i didn't solve this error. My program is running but very laggy and slow. I tried use smaller images and use `asynctask` but my problem is continued. Here is my code. I tried it phone and emulator

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
NotificationManager manager;
public Veri veri,veri1;
int x= 0;

private Timer autoUpdate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    veri1 = new Veri();
    x=veri1.getList().size();

    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);




    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);



    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    onResume();

    new AsyncCaller().execute();



}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////
private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



            autoUpdate = new Timer();
            autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            updateHTML();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 60000);


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


    }

}


////////////////////////////////////

private void updateHTML(){
    // your logic here
    RecyclerAdapter adapter=new RecyclerAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    veri = new Veri();
    int a = veri.getList().size();
    if(a!=x){
        generateNotification(MainActivity.this,"Listede Degisim Var");
    }
    x=a;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

            // search action
        case R.id.action_location_found:
            // location found
            LocationFound();
            return true;



        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void LocationFound() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationFound.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
private void generateNotification(Context context,String message){
    int notificationId = 001;
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, viewIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dikat)
                    .setContentTitle("Bildirim")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                            + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bildirim))

                    .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

here is my data class

```
public class Veri extends ActionBarActivity {

NotificationManager manager;
Notification myNotication;
String ip, db, un, passwords;
Connection connect,conn;
PreparedStatement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
TextView tv;
int position1=0;
Button b1;

ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> data2 = new ArrayList<String>();



public Veri(){
    ip = "x.x.x.x";
    un = "x";
    passwords = "x";
    db = "x";

    connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
    String query = "SELECT Adsoyad,(DATEPART(hour, BeklemeSuresi) * 3600) + (DATEPART(minute, BeklemeSuresi) * 60) + DATEPART(second, BeklemeSuresi) as SecondsFromMidnight,Durum FROM [dbo].[IslemiDevamEdenHasta] (1)";



    try {
       // connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
        stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            int b = (int)rs.getInt("SecondsFromMidnight")/60;
            if(b>50) {
                String id = rs.getString("Adsoyad");
                String id2 = rs.getString("Durum");
                String full = id + " " + id2;
                String a = "" + b;
                data.add(full);
                data2.add(a);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public ArrayList<String> getList() {
    return data;
}
public ArrayList<String> getList2() {
    return data2;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private Connection CONN(String _user, String _pass, String _DB,
                        String _server) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + _server + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + _DB + ";user=" + _user + ";password="
                + _pass + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
}
```

here is my recycler class

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {

public Veri veri = new Veri();
int sayi=0;

ArrayList<String> liste = veri.getList();
ArrayList<String> liste2 = veri.getList2();
static ArrayList<String> liste3 = new ArrayList<String>() ;

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

}
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);



    RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder=new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    liste3.add("a");
    sayi = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < liste3.size(); j++) {
        if (liste3.get(j).equals(liste.get(position))) {
            sayi++;
        }
        if (sayi == 0) {
            holder.tv1.setText(liste.get(position));
            holder.tv2.setText(liste2.get(position));
            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            holder.imageView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder.tv1.setText(liste.get(position));
            holder.tv2.setText(liste2.get(position));
            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_checkin);
        }
    }
}


View.OnClickListener clickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        RecyclerViewHolder vholder = (RecyclerViewHolder) v.getTag();
        int position = vholder.getPosition();
        //Toast.makeText(context,"This is position "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        vholder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_checkin);
        liste3.add(liste.get(position));
    }
};

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return liste.size();
}
```

}

and my error actually not an error but problem

```
09-21 11:45:08.349 20744-20744/com.enginelaldi.recyclerview I/Choreographer: Skipped 948 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-21 11:46:08.444 20744-20744/com.enginelaldi.recyclerview I/Choreographer: Skipped 954 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-21 11:47:08.348 20744-20744/com.enginelaldi.recyclerview I/Choreographer: Skipped 956 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-21 11:48:08.327 20744-20744/com.enginelaldi.recyclerview I/Choreographer: Skipped 953 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you create a thread (asynctask) which creates a timer (autoupdate) which runs every 10 minutes to call updatehtml()  on the ui thread. If so, why not create the timer on the main thread? also could you post the error you get?

Comment: `updateHTML();` method must be in `onPostExecute()` method because `UI` updates in that method.

Comment: thanks for helping piyush but it is not working :(

Comment: In `doInBackground()` method you should perform your long task operations.

Comment: i wrote my thread onpostexecute and created my timer on main thread but  frames are still  too much

Comment: @enginel Just ignore that warning. It won't do any harm to you.

Comment: @NabinKhadka thanks for comment but my app is very laggy

Comment: You are running a background Thread by using an AsyncTask, but looks like you are, in `doInBackground()`,  performing a blocking call, `updateHTML();`, inside your timerTask on the UI thread - this defeats the purpose of the AsyncTask. docs : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html